# Replace a specific value in multiple columns in a csv file with Unix

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I have 1000 columns in a csv file and I want to replace the value "2008" to "1" in every cell "2008" appears, while other cells who do not include "2008" should be "0".
How can i do that ?

What i have :

| Column 1 | ....Column 1000 |
| --- | --- |
| 2008 | 2014 |
| 2010 | 2008 |

desired output :

| Column 1 | ...Column 1000 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 |

Comment: does the file contain a header record (`Column 1    Column 2  ... Column 1000`)?

Comment: assuming the examples are 4-digit years ... do *all* cells in the *csv contain just 4-digit years? or could some of the cells contain other numeric and/or textual data? could a cell contain the number `120080`, or the string `abc2008def` .... and if such values could exist do we also replace these instances of `2008` with `1` (thus leaving us with `110` and `abc1def`)? please update the question with additional details to address these questions

Comment: thank you @markp-fuso i updated my question, each cell contain "2008" should be replaced to 1 and other cells with content not equal to 2008 should be "0".

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to go about it but one of them is that you can use the `sed` command:

`sed -i 's/2008/1/g' yourFile.csv`

- `-i` means `in-place` which means that your file will be edited right there and then.
- `s/...` is for substitution
- the `g` at the end is for global. The default behaviour for sed is to edit the line and stop at the first match, then start on the following line. By adding `g` at the end you're telling sed to keep going down the line and do the changes for each match

Note: Bash is pretty unforgiving. A good way to start experimenting with it would be to back up your file before trying to edit it. There is no Ctrl+z with file editing in bash.

Comment: *"There is no Ctrl+z with file editing in bash"* ... pluse-uno!

Comment: thank you, but i need also to replace every other cell with content not equal to "2008" to zero( see the example above). Furthermore i want to start this algorithm from column 2 to ( not 1 ).Any help is appreciated . Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- any fields that are not equal to the 4-digit `2008` will be changed to `0` (eg, `920089` and `abc2008def` will be changed to `0`)

Sample data file:

```
$ cat test.csv
Column1 Column2 Column3
2008    2014    920089
2010    2008    abc2008def
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }                        # define input/output field delimiter as tab
NR>1  { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)                  # for all but header row (NR>1), loop through all fields and ...
            $i= ($i=="2008") ? 1 : 0         # redefine field based on whether or not equal to "2008"
      }
1                                            # print current row
' test.csv

##########
# or: as a one-liner sans comments

awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} NR>1 {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i= ($i=="2008") ? 1 : 0} 1' test.csv
```

This generates:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
1       0       0
0       1       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Supporting fields like `12008` is more complicated then when all fields are numbers with at most 4 digits:

```
sed -r 's/2008/a/g; s/[0-9]+/0/g; s/a/1/g' file
```

Without the restriction of the fields, use `awk`.

Comment: Thank you Walter, can i start from column 2 to 1000 ( my first column is ID numbers and i dont want to lose them).

Comment: I don't know what your field delimiter is. When it is a semicolon, you can use something like `echo "248;0;1;2;2007;2008;2008;2009;2008" | sed -r 's/;2008/;a/g; s/;[0-9]+/;0/g; s/;a/;1/g'`. With TABs, use `sed -r 's/\t2008/\ta/g; s/\t[0-9]+/\t0/g; s/\ta/\t1/g' file`

Comment: Next time, please add example input and output as text in your question and think like other things that can be relevant like the first column and information what data can be in the columns (are `22008` and `abc` possible). And the field sep. Helping someone is much easier when it is completely clear what is wanted.

Comment: Thank you yes, i wrote in the question body that i have csv ( comma)